# Model Theory: the Hodges book

Tags: logic, notation, model-theory

In the large Wilfrid Hodges book: [Model Theory](http://62.182.86.140/main/580000/096c7550c0485082186db146cb7f47d5/Wilfrid%20Hodges%20-%20Model%20Theory%20%28Encyclopedia%20of%20Mathematics%20and%20its%20Applications%29%20%282008%29.djvu) I have 2 easy questions,first on the page 164, example 2, $V$ is exactly $A$:
they begin with
Let $V$ be an infinite vector space (in my opinion this should read "Let $A$ be an infinite vector space") but then they say something about $A$:
Thus again $A$ is minimal.

Next, what should I take for $D$ in 6.4.1. in the proof of the fact 4.5.1 ?
What corresponds to $A,B$ and $C$ from the proof of 4.5.1.(the first snippet) to in 6.4.1. (the second snippet) ?

Please see 2 snippets below.

[image]

*** $\mathbf{second\  snippet}$ ***

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to prove 4.5.1 directly (using compactness) without going through 6.4.1?

Comment: @PrimoPetri No, I haven't. Besides I think that I would not be able to prove this way, I would like to understand the suggested solution through 6.4.1.

Comment: In example 2 there is a typo. Read A=V.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $C$ is a counterexample (not $B$!).
Say, $c$ is a tuple of parameters in $C$ and $\delta(x,c)$ is a formula such that for every $n$

$$C\models\exists^{\ge n} x \ \ \psi(x)\wedge\delta(x,c)$$

$$C\models\exists^{\ge n} x \ \ \psi(x)\wedge\neg\delta(x,c)$$

Let $B=A$, $D\succeq B$, and $g:C\to D$ be as in Theorem 6.4.1. Then

$$D\models\exists^{\ge n} x \ \ \psi(x)\wedge\delta(x,gc)$$

$$D\models\exists^{\ge n} x \ \ \psi(x)\wedge\neg\delta(x,gc)$$

This proves (a)$\rightarrow$(b) of Fact 4.5.1.

(I insist that proving Fact 4.5.1 by elementary amalgamation is insane.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not follow what have you accomplished by these two rows; they seem to me that they are **contradictory** anyway: $$C\models\exists^{\ge n} x \ \ \psi(x)\wedge\delta(x,c)$$ 


$$C\models\exists^{\ge n} x \ \ \psi(x)\wedge\neg\delta(x,c).$$ What says $\delta(x,c)$ there ?

Comment: They are not contradictory since given that $C$ is a counter example to the claim, then $\phi(x)$ defines an infinite-coinfinite set inside of $C$. If such a $\delta$ did not exist then in fact $\psi(x)$ would be minimal in $C$.

Comment: Your snippets do not contain Hodges' definition of minimal set. So I have used the standard one: there is a definable subset $\delta(C,b)$ of $\psi(C)$ that is infinite and coinfinite.

Comment: @PrimoPetri Right. Luckily I've given a link to the entire book in the first row of my OQ.